# How to pass instance of one class to another via constructor

Tags: c++

I have a simple question. How would you go about passing an instance of a class to a constructor of another class in c++? I have experience in C, however I am struggling with the syntax of c++.

For example say I have Class A and want to pass and Instance of it to Class B.

```
A.h

class A {
   A();
   virtual ~A(); 

   public:
   B *newb;   
}


A.cpp

A::A() {

   newb = new B(this);

}

b.h

class B {
  B(A *instanceA);
  virtual ~B(); 


}
```

Could someone please provide me with a simple example? It would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I tried this concept with my current code, but kept getting errors. Sorry I wanted to make sure that I used the right principle. This is a snippet of the code that I am currently working on.

```
     //SentencSelection.h

        class SentenceSelection
        {   

        public:
            SentenceSelection(TestBenchGui *test);
            virtual ~SentenceSelection();

               //do stuff
        };

     //SentencSelection.cpp

        #include <iostream>
        #include "SentenceSelection.h"

        using namespace std;

        SentenceSelection::SentenceSelection(TestBenchGui *test)
        {
             //do stuff
        }

        SentenceSelection::~SentenceSelection()
        {

        }

    //TestBenchGui.h
     #include "SentenceSelection.h"


    class TestBenchGui
    {

    public:
        TestBenchGui();
        virtual ~TestBenchGui();


    private:
        SentenceSelection *selection;

    };

    //TestBenchGui.cpp

    #include "TestBenchGui.h"
    #include "SentenceSelection.h"


    using namespace std;


    TestBenchGui::TestBenchGui()
    {
        selection = new SentenceSelection(this);
    }

    TestBenchGui::~TestBenchGui()
    {

    }
```

When I compile this in eclipse I get the follwing error "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token"  for the line - "SentenceSelection::SentenceSelection(TestBenchGui test)"  in SentenceSelection.h.

Comment: Looks like you already have a simple example. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: You have something weird. A owns a B*. Why would B be constructed with A* and destroyed with ~A() ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Did you compiled you program? What result you got? You asking for simple example, but you already have it.

Comment: Too broad. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for an introductory book on C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code you have does pretty much what you are asking, but there are a couple of syntax errors that are probably holding you back from compilation (and thus leading to some confusion). Below is code that I put in a single file (main.cpp) and was able to compile. I added some comments and print statements to highlight the difference between DECLARATIONS and IMPLEMENTATIONS:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// forward declaration so we can refer to it in A
class B;

// define A's interface
class A { 
public:
     // member variables
     B *newb;   

     // constructor declaration
     A();

     // destructor declaration
     virtual ~A();
};  // note the semicolon that ends the definition of A as a class

class B { 
public:
    // B constructor implementation
    B(A *instanceA){cout << "I am creating a B with a pointer to an A at " << instanceA << endl;}

    // B destructor implementation
    virtual ~B(){cout << "Destructor of B" << endl;}
};  // note the semicolon that ends the definition of B as a class

// A constructor implementation
A::A(){
     cout << "I am creating an A at " << this << ", allocating a B on the heap..." << endl;
    newb = new B(this);
}

// A destructor implementation
A::~A(){
    cout << "Destructor of A, deleting my B...." << endl;
    delete newb;
}
int main(){
    A an_a;
}
```

Output for my system from running the above program:

```
I am creating an A at 0x7fff64884ba0, allocating a B on the heap...
I am creating a B with a pointer to an A at 0x7fff64884ba0
Destructor of A, deleting my B....
Destructor of B
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will give it a try.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I did not have the forward declaration of the class.I  appreciate the effort!

Comment: Why do you need that though? Should it not be enough to #include the header file where class B is defined?

Answer (score 0):

> For example say I have Class A and want to pass and Instance of it to Class B.

If you intend to pass a pointer to the instance, then you have already figured it out. The constructor that you declared takes an `A*` as an argument:

```
B(A *instanceA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
 public:
 B(){};
 int x;
 ~B(){};
};


class A
{
  public:
  A(){}; // default constructor
  A(B& b) // constructor taking B
  {
    y = b.x;
  }
  ~A(){};
  int y;
};




   int main()
   {

     B myB;
     myB.x = 69;
     A myA(myB);
     cout << myA.y << endl;
     return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I answer strictly your question:
If you want to pass a instance on a constructor best practice is pass as a reference:

```
 class CA{
     CB &b;
   public:
      CA( CB &p_b) : b(p_b){};
      virtual ~CA();
```

};

But in your example you have a classes with cross references that is another case

Comment: That is not "best practice" at all but depends entirely on the type of the object which is passed and on what else the constructor is going to do with the argument.

Comment: @Christian  Do you agree that in same situation is better pass a reference than a pointer? and for that question I think that it fits perfectly. Anyway  I accept your critic

Comment: The situation is too artificial to know what kind of parameter to choose. It could be `CB`, `CB&`, `CB const&`, `CB*`, `CB const*`,  `CB&&`,  `std::unique_ptr<CB>`, `std::shared_ptr<CB>` or further combinations thereof. The point is that there is no generally accepted "best practice" for this.